# What networking system is my Pi using?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi-os

What networking system is my Pi using?
Recent changes with Bookworm mean many of the older methods don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a number of Pi (mostly headless) running a range of Operating Systems and different network managers.

I had a number of code fragments to check networking but a different set is needed for each so I decided to write a single script that would run on most systems and show significant network settings.

Download latest from https://github.com/Milliways2/Raspberry-Pi-Utilities/blob/main/netstats

```
#! /bin/sh
# This script prints useful diagnostics for common Pi networking systems

# Function to print coloured headings
#  delete "tput" lines for plain output
print_head () {
 tput setaf 6
 echo $1
 tput sgr 0
}

checkactive () {
if [ $(systemctl is-active $1) = 'active' ]; then
    echo $1 'active'
fi
}

print_head "- Networking System"
# Check status of networking system
checkactive 'systemd-networkd'
checkactive 'dhcpcd'
checkactive 'NetworkManager'
checkactive 'networking'

print_head "- IP addresses & routes"
# Print IP addresses & routes
ip a
echo
ip r

print_head "- Network Devices"
ls /sys/class/net   # network devices

print_head "- Connected WiFi"
# Get SSID of connected WiFi (WRONG if AP!)
if [ -e /sys/class/net/wlan0 ]; then
    if [ $(systemctl is-active 'NetworkManager') = 'active' ]; then
        nmcli connection show |  awk '/wlan0/ {print $1}'
    else
        wpa_cli -i wlan0 status | grep -w ssid | awk -F'[=]' '{print $2}'
    fi
fi

print_head "- Available WiFi connections"
if [ -e /sys/class/net/wlan0 ]; then
    if [ $(systemctl is-active 'NetworkManager') = 'active' ]; then
        nmcli connection show |  awk '/wifi/ {print $1}'
    else
        wpa_cli list_networks | awk '/any/ {print $2}'
    fi
fi
```

The output on Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm 64bit is:-

```
- Networking System
NetworkManager active
networking active
- IP addresses & routes
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:02:23:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.2.74/24 brd 10.1.2.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d388:e56f:5ecf:406d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:02:23:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe02:2325/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

default via 10.1.2.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.2.74 metric 100 
10.1.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.74 metric 100 
10.42.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 600 
- Network Devices
eth0  lo  wlan0
- Connected WiFi
Hotspot
- Available WiFi connections
Hotspot
WiFi-B13A
WiFi-B13A-5G
```

Comment: I've not tried this, but:  Have you considered putting this script up on GitHub?