# Raspberry Pi 0 W, no network

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to get the Raspberry Pi 0 W on my wifi network and failing.  This is what I've done:

```
1.  Insert 64GB SD Card into USB holder.
2.  Insert USB holder into USB port and launch Raspberry Pi Imager v1.8.5 on my iMAC.
3.  Using the Pi Imager application:
    Choose Device:  Raspberry Pi Zero (Models Zero, Zero W, Zero WH)
    Choose OS:      Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy, 32-bit) A port of Debian Bullseye with security updates and desktop environment (Recommended)
    Choose Storage: Mass Storage Device Media - 63.8 GB
4.  Click NEXT
5.  Edit Settings, assigning hostname RPi0W, setting username and password, SSID and Password, Wireless LAN country to GB, Time zone to  Europe/London, Keyboard layout to gb, Services enable SSH, Save and click YES. 
6.  All existing data on 'Mass Storage Device Media' will be erased.  Are you sure you want to continue?  Click YES button.
7.  Wait for progress Writing and Verifying to reach 100%.

    SD card is auto-ejected, I close Raspberry Pi Imager.

8.  Insert SD card into Raspberry Pi 0W.
9.  Connect Raspberry Pi keyboard which has USB mouse connected to keyboard USB hub.
10. Connect HDMI cable using adapter.
11. Connect power to Raspberry Pi 0W.
12. Power up Raspberry Pi 0W.
13. Wait for power up process to complete and desktop to be ready for use, takes a while (5-10) minutes.
14. From the Raspberry menu, open the Preferences submenu and select Raspberry Pi Configuration.

    Network at Boot, check that it is on, slider needs to be on the right.

15. Click the Interfaces tab.

    SSH on

16. Click on OK button.
```

I have a wpa_supplicant.conf file which exists in /etc/wpa_supplicant, I've copied it into /boot and rebooted, but when the desktop is up the network top right shows wlan0: Not associated and click it shows No Wireless LAN interfaces found.

Would could explain this because I've reviewed the content of wpa_supplicant.conf and the content is correct.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=UK

network {
    ssid=“my network SSID”
    psk=“my SSID password”
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

[Edit] Edit wpa_supplicant.conf changing country to GB, moved back into /boot and rebooted, still nothing.

Comment: Where did you prep that wpa_supplicant.conf?  I notice the double quotes are some higher order unicode character, and not the basic ascii `"` that you can get from shift + single quote (on US keyboards).  It may not like that.  You should also be able to get some diagnostics from `sudo journalctl -xeu wpa_supplicant`, I *think* NetworkManager runs it as a discrete service (if it says "none such" I'm wrong).

Comment: @goldilocks, I think thats just the way they are presented here, I used Visual Studio Code on my iMAC.

Comment: No, they are presented that way because they have a distinctly different character value than normal ascii quotes.  That file is being parsed by *computer software*, not a human being, and it uses the double quote character (ASCII value 34) as a delimiter.  
 What you have right there is not, and so it (very likely) may not see it as a quoted string at all and either ignore it or regard the whole string to include the fancy unicode quotes...

Comment: @goldilocks, I will try it out and let you know, however on my iMAC which is where I create the files before transferring to the SD-Card, if I use "Hex Fiend" and in the right panel select the quote it highlights the hex in the left panel which is 22, so yes 34 decimal, which is a double quote in the ASCII table.

Comment: Well done, meanwhile I hacked an answer out..

Comment: BTW, I actually didn't edit your question as per my previous comment so it may be worth considering that those quotes got there somehow and they are not the standard ascii (I put them in a hex reader too);  the software here would not have done that.  It may have been your web browser, but you should check the version on the Pi in case it happened at some other point for whatever reason.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm just looking at your methodology in detail; I didn't do this before because I've never used the imager and so don't have much to say about it, *but* as far as I've noticed here, I don't think "add wpa_supplicant.conf to /boot" is done anymore; it isn't mentioned here in the imager instructions: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#networking     ...But what is referred to there is giving the imager your wifi credentials.  Presumably it then writes a conf for you and puts it in the right place (which is not /boot, it's /etc/wpa_supplicant/).

Comment: @goldilocks, I've just re-flashed the SD card again, so I will try it without copying ssh or wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: I don't think that wpa_suplicant is used any more. You should, since you are using RPImager, set the network name and password in the settings. Also, they have a setting to turn ssh on.

Comment: @NomadMaker, yes, I did that, its rebooting now. When I first inserted the SD card a text box showed "Generating SSH keys" which I think is encouraging, then it rebooted again, waiting now...

Comment: @goldilocks Finally it works and I didn't transfer wpa_supplicant.conf, so the imager does do it all, there is so much old and wrong information out there!  Big thank you!  Correct your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland is **GB** NOT UK.

You state "Wireless LAN country to GB" so I don't know where you got your wpa_supplicant.conf  which should have been set by imager.

Comment: So I corrected the country changing it to GB, was hoping that was it, still no network.

Comment: You could try my network diagnostic script https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/147226/8697

Comment: as it turned out the solution was not to add a wpa_supplicant.conf as the Imager sets everything up correctly based on the configuration supplied during flashing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the wpa_supplicant.conf file is in the correct location. Since you mentioned copying it to /boot, that should be fine. Just make sure it's not in any subdirectories within /boot.

Comment: As far as I can see when the Raspberry Pi 0 W boots I moves the wpa_supplicant.conf to /etc/wpa_supplicant/

Comment: I corrected the country changing it to GB, moved the file into /boot again and rebooted, still nothing.