Headless Raspberry Pi 2 W suddenly stopped connecting to Wi-Fi
I bought this Raspberry Pi 2 W about 1 month ago. I installed the lite headles OS using the official app. Everything was working perfectly, I was able to SSH and use it, until today. I am not aware of changing anything, the Wi-Fi settings are the same and other machines are connecting. The contents of /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf were
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="MyWiFi"
        psk=cf8af2ee7dfc4acfe80eda3fe148d5df9blahblahblah
}

and just now I manually changed (connecting the SD card to my laptop PC) it to
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="MyWiFi"
        psk="MyPassword"
}

following this answer. Still nothing.
What else can I try?
/etc/os-release:
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

/etc/rpi-issue:
Raspberry Pi reference 2024-03-12
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, fbaa2a26c810dc53305754575f299bc2319d46f2, stage2


You did not tell us which OS + version you're using but at a guess: you need to add the country code to the config file. See the answer you linked to above

Don't know why would the country matter, also was not there originally. Anyhow, I just added it and it still does not work. I added OS version info to the question.

DHCP server pool run empty?

The linked Answer does explain Country Code and you appear to have used the Pi imager to setup the OS (which is practically the only way to setup a headless system) and you should have been prompted to enter regional settings (including CC). CC has been essential for years (at least for many networks).
The wpa_supplicant files you listed are probably identical (if the SSID and passcode are the same). The imager encodes the passcode into a 256bit psk.
The upshot of this is that your problem is unlikely to be due to the files you listed.
I suggest you restore from your backup.
I haven't done a fresh installation of Bullseye for years and am not even sure which networking system it uses. The script in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/147226/8697 is what I use to identify networks.
